# How to add a class using less than from a range in input?

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, input, plyr.js

I'm having problems with my code. It's supposed to add a class called `test` to `.js-volume` when a range in an input is less than 30. It can work if the value in the input is exactly at 30 `this.value == 30` but using less than or greater than doesn't work.

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.plyr-volume input').on('input',function(){
    if(parseInt(this.value > 30)) {
      $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
    } else {
      $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
    }
  });
  $('.plyr__volume input').trigger('input');
})();
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/JQeEry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this.value` is actually returning decimals, so really the input is never going above `30` in your example, and wrapping it in a `parseInt` is making it return 0 no matter what.

So you could do some conversions to return whole numbers, or you can just grab one of the attributes in the input, that has the "value".

```
$(function() {
  $('.plyr-volume input').on('input',function(){
    // find the 'aria-valuenow' attribute, returns whole numbers
    var val = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');   
    if(val > 30) {
      $('.js-volume').addClass('test');
    } else {
      $('.js-volume').removeClass('test');
    }
  });
  $('.plyr__volume input').trigger('input');
});
```